# Issues with plotting years

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

Code was ran in RStudio ( version 0.98.1091, R 3.1.2) on a Mac running 10.10. Not enough reputation to post image so please run the R code if you can.

My issue is with the way my plots are displaying my points as points instead of bars. I have a data frame defined as below.

```
ebola = c(0,26,1,2,0,2,0,0)
dengue = c(474,1943,2209,963,1498,1720,1360,1364)
rabies = c(1336,1353,1938,3116,908,1264,2499,1130)
year = c("2007","2008","2009","2010","2011","2012","2013","2014")
virus_data_by_year = data.frame(year,ebola,dengue,rabies)
virus_data_by_year
```

The above functions work fine. My problem comes when I try to plot let's say year vs. ebola with the following function:

```
with(virus_data_by_year,plot(year,ebola,type="p",xlab="year",ylab="ebola"))
```

Even though I use the point element in my type argument it shows

[image: bad graph]

My issue with the above plot is that it shows my data as horizontal bars instead of as points. When I change the type argument to a line it still displays the same graph instead of having points connected by a line like below.

```
plot (year,ebola, type = "b")
```

[image: good graph]

I can graph it perfectly fine if I graph the original two vectors so this seem to be a data frame issue. Furthermore it's limited to the year one because if I use the function below it still plots a line graph fine.

```
with(virus_data_by_year,plot(ebola,dengue,type = "b"))
```

Comment: Convert `year` to valid date format, `year = as.Date(year, "%Y")`.

Comment: Why is this question receiving negative credits? It provides details on the software used, a replicative example, and evidence of own effort including what works and what doesn't work? Is it just because the person in question was not aware that in this case year needs to be in the right format (which apparently has been asked elsewhere)?

Comment: @Richard I do not know too, but you can upvote it again... I've done it.

Comment: @ckluss thanks, when I tried to upvote it earlier, I made it actually more negative, so removed my 'up'vote. Will upvote it again, once the timer has been reset.

Comment: `plot` is a generic and here `plot.factor` is called since your "virus_data_by_year$year" is a "factor" (was made a "factor" after the call to `data.frame(.)`). And `plot.factor` behaves the way is seen. See for example `plot(x = 1:10, y = sample(10))` vs `plot(x = factor(1:10), y = sample(10))`

Answer (score 1):

Convert `year` to valid date format, `year = as.Date(year, "%Y")`.

Comment: Note the above answer was posted as a comment by @Khashaa